# `session_start` setting new cookie in PHP

Tags: php, session, cookies

I am working in a Php application and I have a problem regarding session management.

Whenever I request an an asset (by requesting a file file an extension) that isn't there, I correctly receive a 404 response, but a new session cookie is set. Hence the next time I make a request I am logged out.

The new cookie is set when the call to `session_start()` is made. It seems that Php is not able to understand the fact that there is already a session cookie present in the HTTP request and therefore it generates a new one.

To make everything more interesting, this happens only in our production environment, where we have Zend Server with Php 5.4.23. The problem does not manifest itself locally where we have just Php 5.4.16.

Do you have any suggestion on how I could solve or investigate futher this issue?

Comment: Are you browsing your production website through **https** ? (and not your local dev instance)

Comment: yes, production get redirected automatically to https

Comment: Are you using secure cookies ? https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SecureFlag

Comment: no, the `session.cookie_secure` is `Off`

Comment: Are you certain both cookies (the old one and the new one) are perfectly identical except for the identifier ? (domain, path, secure bit), see Chrome dev tools/Application/Cookies to check that out.

Comment: yes, only the identifier changes. It looks like php is not able to understand that there is a current session and therefore creates a new one

Comment: Since the browser identifies cookies by name, creating two with the same name and set of parameters is not possible. There is a difference between the two cookies, I've told you how to spot it in my comments (look more closely). And from there work you way out to the root cause and solutions. Posting some screenshots might help others to help you, too.